# Computation of a simple stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

For $t \in [0,T]$. consider two stochastic integrals with a nonnegative constant integrand $c$

1. $$\mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^{t(\omega)^* \wedge T} c \cdot dW_t \right]$$

where $t^*$ is random stopping time, and $W_t$ is Wiener process.

In this simple situation, "can I just interchange the expectation and the integral sign" (By Fubini's result?) and get

$$\mathbb{E}\left [\int_0^{t(\omega)^* \wedge T} c \cdot dW_t \right] = ? =c \cdot \int_0^{t(\omega)^* \wedge T} \mathbb{E}[ dW_t ]= 0?$$

2.Consider another stochastic integral

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^{t(\omega)^* \wedge T} dt \right]$$

I know $\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^{t(\omega)^* \wedge T} c \cdot dt \right] = c \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[ t(\omega)^* \wedge T \right]$, but can I compute this expectation more explicitly? (I attempt to get rid of the random stopping time and get a deterministic-like result)

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1), we have $$E[\int_0^{t(\omega)^*\wedge T}c dW_s]=cE[W_{t(\omega)^*\wedge T}]$$.

$t(\omega)^*\wedge T$ is a stopping time for which is bounded by $T$. Hence by the optinoal stopping theorem 
$$E[W_{t(\omega)^*\wedge T}]=E[W_0]=0$$

For 2). This depends on the exact definition of your $t(\omega)^*$. For a general stopping time this can not be simplified further. You can get an upper bound by $T$ since $t(\omega)^*\wedge T\le T$ for any $T\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thanks for your great help. But for (2), can we also find a deterministic lower bound also?

Comment: @Chung-HanHsieh a lower bound would be 0, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but I mean could we find something in between? like $0 < ? \leq E[t(\omega)^* \wedge T] \leq T$ ?

Comment: @Chung-HanHsieh I guess you ment $E[t(\omega)^*\wedge T]$ in your last comment. Again this depends on the definition of $t(\omega)^*$